# Will the product of a real valued matrix and its transpose always have a real eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve this really interesting problem, taken from "Berkeley Problmes in Mathematics" by Souza and Silva
[https://www.amazon.com/Berkeley-Problems-Mathematics-Problem-Books/dp/0387204296](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387204296)
Trying to make headway, I've noticed that if the last two statements are correct, then $M^T(Mu)=\sigma^2 u$, so in other words, there exists an eigenvector $u$ with the eigenvalue $\sigma^2$.
Therefore, I have two questions, and I would dearly love a proof or counter-example:[image]

1. Is it true that $M^TM$ must have at least a (real) eigenvector?
2. I strongly suspect this $\sigma$ they talk of is the operator norm of $M$. Is this true?
3. Is this a dead-end way to try to solve this problem. Should I try something else?

Of course, everything is real-valued here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $M^\top M$ is called the *[Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)* of $M$.

One important property of the Gramian is that it is symmetric. Indeed, one easily checks that
$$
(M^\top M)^\top
= M^\top (M^\top)^\top
= M^\top M
$$
This means that [the spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) applies to $M^\top M$.

The spectral theorem says that every symmetric matrix $S$ can be factored as $S=QDQ^\top$ where $D$ is real-diagonal and $Q$ is orthogonal. This means that every $n\times n$ symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues and that there is an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $S$.

Applying the spectral theorem to $M^\top M$ immediately implies that $M^\top M$ has real eigenvalues and that there is an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $M^\top $M.

One can actually say a little more. The Gramian $M^\top M$ is *[positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix)* so its eigenvalues are nonnegative. If $M$ is full column rank, then $M^\top M$ is positive definite, so its eigenvalues are all positive.

Answer (score 0):

***The spectral theorem***: if $A$ is real valued matrix then $A^TA$ is symmetric. Such matrices must have a whole ON system of eigenvectors with strictly non negative real eigenvalues. It follows for example directly from for example Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) which is a more powerful result regarding $A$

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, obvious once you realize $M^TM$ is symmetric.
2. yes, can you prove it?
3. I think this is a good way to do it. Be somewhat careful in finding condition (2) since $v$ is a unit vector. I have not ideas besides doing this by construction from condition (3). have fun.